# Issue with using Orchard CMS and the SyntaxHighlighter module

Tags: orchardcms

I'm probably overlooking something simple here, but is there a simple example of displaying a highlighted text block in a blog post (after installing the module).  I suspect I may not be placing the required JavaScript files in the right place...

Answer (score 1):

After installing the module did you go to the features area in the Dashboard and activate the feature?  Modules are installed with their features inactive by default.